# Redirect all url to the http//www with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Using .htaccess, 
I need to redirect all requests from

http://domain,

https://domain

https://www.domain

to

http://www.domain

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.example)?.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to `https://www` you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com℅{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```